# Android - merge and include

Tags: android

I want to use switch button in my app. As its API is 11 and switch needs API higher than 14, I decided to use `merge` and `include` method but I get this error in `values-v14/compound_switch.xml` file : `Element merge must be declerd`. here are my files, what is the problem?

Main layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/compound_switch" />
```

layout/compound_switch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/night_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:checked="false" />

</merge>
```

values-v14/compound_switch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/night_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your layout that has the switch from the folder `values-v14` to a folder called `layout-v14`. Layouts should be in the `layout` folder. The values folder is for colors, dimensions, attributes, etc.